# Происхождение слова "кудесник"

Tags: этимология

Задумалась над словом "кудесник", но так и не смога понять, как оно образовалось и русское ли вообще.
Что по этому поводу могут сказать специалисты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Об этом говорит Фасмер, на которого ссылается Вики:"Происходит от др.-русск. кудесъ «чары, колдовство»; отсюда куде́сник, ку́десить «чудить, подшучивать», вятск. Связано с чудо — первонач. *кудо, из праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. чоудо род. п. чоудесе , укр. чу́до, мн. чудеса́.

От др-р. "чудо" образуется глагол чудить-восхвалять, прославлять, удивлять, отсюда совр. "чудить" - "совершать нелепые поступки".Потом значения слегка расходятся.От "чудить"-удивлять - чудак и чудиться - удивляться, дивиться, от него значение"возникать в воображении, казаться". От "чудо"образовалось и "чудный" -достойный удивления, а затем - очаровательный и чудной--странный, вызывающий недоумение. От формы чудеса-чудесный - "волшебный" и "дивный, прекрасный". Так что оттенков у слова много.И слово кудесник тоже имеет 2 значения:1.нар.-поэт. волшебник; тот, кто делает что-либо сверхъестественное ◆ Скажи мне, кудесник, любимец богов, // Что сбудется в жизни со мною?  А. С. Пушкин, «Песнь о вещем Олеге»
2.перен., разг. выдающийся мастер ◆ Он настоящий кудесник, такие блюда готовит — пальчики оближешь!

Comment: >Об этом говорит Фасмер, на которого ссылается Вики:  
  
О чем?

Answer (score 4):

Это слово этимологически имеет тот же корень, что и у "чуда". В славянских языках "к" иногда чередуется с "ч" (ср. *печь-пеку*). Кудесник - это "чудесник" (чудотворец).

Comment: В гневе начал он кудесть -   
И гонца велел повесить.  
(С)Наше все.
Какой уж тут чудотворец... Кудесить - "чудить". Другое значение.

Comment: @behemothus, "чудить' и "чудак" в русском языке тоже присутствуют. А судя по современному значению, кудесник - это тот кто творит чудеса, а не чудачества.

Comment: >"чудить' и "чудак" в русском языке тоже присутствую  
  
Ваши откровения становятся все забавнее.

Answer (score -1):

Слово пошло от финского "кудеса" - рукавица или же бубен. Кудесник - финско-чудский шаман с бубном. Отсюда и чудь, чудеса, чудик, чудный.

Comment: Скажите, каким образом вы сделали такой вывод? Бубен как муз. инструмент по-фински *tamburiini*, бубенец - *kulkunen*. Рукавица же либо *kinnas*, либо *käsine*. О каких "кудесах" вы говорите?